# Rails radio buttons not passing value consistently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

I've been having some issues with my radio buttons. This is the HTML generated by my ruby:

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/uanswers" class="new_uanswer" id="new_uanswer"         method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" /><input name="authenticity_token"    type="hidden" value="tiJsYNr71Zqo+R5TheG2nvB3ownJ4iKbmwMfA/11TXg=" /></div> 
        <table> 
    <input id="uanswer_answer_id" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="hidden" /> <tr> 
    <td><input id="uanswer_answer_id_12" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="radio" value="12" /></td> 
    <td><label for="uanswer_answer_id">!</label></td> <td> | Count: 0</td> </tr> <input id="uanswer_answer_id" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="hidden" />
    <tr> 
    <td><input id="uanswer_answer_id_13" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="radio" value="13" /></td>
    <td><label for="uanswer_answer_id">!!</label></td> <td> | Count: 0</td> </tr> <input id="uanswer_answer_id" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="hidden" />
    <tr>
    <td><input id="uanswer_answer_id_14" name="uanswer[answer_id]" type="radio" value="14" /></td>
    <td><label for="uanswer_answer_id">!!!</label></td> <td> | Count: 0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, it only works when I select the third radio button. For example, if I select the first or the second, the "answer_id' field in the params hash is blank. However, if I select the third, it is the correct value: 14.
Why could it be doing this? The HTML seems correct.

EDIT: Here is the ERB behind this HTML

```
<%= form_for(uanswer) do |f| %>
  <table>
  <% answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :answer_id %>
    <tr>
      <% unless current_user.has_answered? question %>
        <td><%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= f.label :answer_id, answer.answer %></td>
      <td> | Count: <%= answer.count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <% unless current_user.has_answered? question %>
    <%= f.submit "Answer!" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple hidden inputs with `name="uanswer[answer_id]"` and radio buttons with the same `name` attribute? And why are the `<label>`s referencing the hidden inputs? Your HTML also has several elements with the same `id` and that's invalid HTML (and possibly the source of your trouble). Your HTML doesn't make any sense to me, what does the original ERB look like?

Comment: I'm new to rails and such, and the radio_button function doesn't seem to have very good documentation, at least for me.

Comment: I added the ERB to the original question. Looking back, I probably don't need the hidden fields, but would that change the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: All sorts of strange things can happen when you duplicate `id`s. And binding the `<label>`s to hidden inputs is strange at best. And duplicating `name` attributes between radio buttons and other things is a bit odd too. I suspect that everything will work fine if you get rid of the hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The hidden field for answer_id could be necessary (it will make server clear answer_id if no radio button is checked), but it was put in wrong place. It should be out of the loop:

```
<%= form_for(uanswer) do |f| %>
  <table>
  <%= f.hidden_field :answer_id %>
  <% answers.each do |answer| %>
    <tr>
      <% unless current_user.has_answered? question %>
        <td><%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= f.label :answer_id, answer.answer %></td>
      <td> | Count: <%= answer.count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <% unless current_user.has_answered? question %>
    <%= f.submit "Answer!" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```